# Why run Android Virtual Device so lag in ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use the dual OS on my laptop. When I run the android virtual device via windows, it is so smooth. But when I change to my ubuntu 20.04, it is lag. Can I set up anything in ubuntu to test my app on an Android virtual device?

Comment: You can use `Anbox` that's very useful

Answer (score 1):

Android Studios drains a lot of RAM while it is functioning and moreover that you are using dual operating systems. There will be a lot of burden on your processor to run both VirtualBox and Android Studios. That is the reason you are getting lag. Please check your processor speed and RAM specifications of your system and try to run Android Studios on your base operating system.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clearing question. When i write dual OS , it means dual boot operating system. I think not beacause of process or ram. When i use android x86 to emulator it quite smooth. But it is quite complicated to connect to android studio. Just emulator attach with android studio is so stuck.